# What can be gleaned from looking at a domain-colored graph of a complex function?

Tags: complex-analysis, intuition, visualization

Functions from $\mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ are hard to visualize because of their 4-dimensional nature. One nice way of looking at them is by what's called [domain coloring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_coloring). An example from the wiki article is shown below.

When we look at the graph of a real function ($\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$), we can get a feel for some of the function's properties: where its zeros are, if it's continuous, if it's differentiable, etc.

My question is what kinds of properties of complex functions can we "see" by looking at a domain coloring? In the example below, we can obviously see where the zeros are and where it blows up. I'm wondering, can we tell if a function is analytic? A rational function? Can we estimate an integral like we could by looking at a real graph?

[image]

$f(z) = \frac{(z^2 − 1)(z − 2 − i)^2}{(z^2 + 2 + 2i)}$

Answer (score 6):

Hans Lundmark's pages on [domain coloring](http://www.mai.liu.se/~halun/complex/domain_coloring-unicode.html), and [his page on Elliptic functions](http://www.mai.liu.se/~halun/complex/elliptic/) is good places to start. (Picard's great theorems, Lucas's theorem, Weierstrass $\wp$ function)

I don't think we can see that a function is rational  -- just moving the roots in the function that you have displayed above by $\pi/100$ in some random direction would be sufficient to make it not a rational function, but the picture would more or less look the same.

Comment: I suspect that there is no assumed restriction to rational functions with algebraic coefficients, in which case moving the zeros by $\pi/100$ wouldn't necessarily make it not a rational function.

Comment: New address: http://users.mai.liu.se/hanlu09/complex

Answer (score 3):

See also [Phase Plots of a Complex Function: A Journey in Illustration](http://www.ams.org/notices/201106/rtx110600768p.pdf) by Wegert & Semmler and the book "Visual Complex Functions" by Wegert which is an expansion of that paper.

The phase of an analytic function uniquely determines the function, up to a positive constant scaling factor. So mathematically, you can determine the function modulo a constant. Some insights might not be psychologically realistic that are theoretically possible.

You can tell the difference between a zero and a pole by the direction in which the colors swirl around the point. And you can tell the order of the zero or pole by how many times the colors complete a cycle around the point.

If a function is not analytic, you may be able to tell that from the phase plot.

Comment: +1 Any hints on how to tell if a function's analytic? I suspect you'd need to train your eye and brain to recognize colors that are "out of order".

Comment: Can you tell whether a function $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is real-analytic (or even smooth) by looking at its graph in $\mathbb{R}^2$? Except where there are obvious singularities, I don't think I could...

Comment: @JesseMadnick I think I could—try me!

Answer (score 1):

IMHO to analyse the image after transformation one must **know the image and it's coordinate before transformation**. For example 2 different initial images :

cartesian grid before : [image]

polar grid before [image]

and after transformation ( Moebius )

cartesian after : [image]

polar after : [image]

One can use initial image which highlights the futures which are important and see how they change after transformation.

HTH